# pyspark - Spark hbase connector throws failed to find data source

Tags: pyspark, hbase

I'm trying to connect to hbase from Pyspark using SHC API by referring the below link.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/143802/read-hbase-with-pyspark-from-jupyter-notebook.html

**Sample code:**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Hbase Read").getOrCreate()
data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'
catalog = ''.join("""{
    "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"table"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "firstcol":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "secondcol":{"cf":"cf", "col":"col1", "type":"int"}
    }
}""".split())
df = spark.read \
    .options(catalog=catalog) \
    .format(data_source_format) \
    .load()
df.show()
```

**Spark-submit:**

```
spark-submit  --packages com.hortonworks:shc:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ TestHbaseRead.py
```

i'm getting this error.

Error log:

```
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
        at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Hi Shankar, Were you able to find resolution for this? I am also facing similar issue. Kindly share your solution if you have found something. Regards

Comment: @ChauhanB: for me the problem was I have downloaded the jar and added the jar location when running spark submit, I guess that was the problem.. it was some time before..

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have finally resolved this issue and provided full end to end implementation of how to use SHC, as response to my query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826218/what-is-the-best-possible-way-of-interacting-with-hbase-using-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment96435984_54826218