# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark when pyspark read hbase table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I use pyspark to read hbase table as a dataframe, but it went some wrong:

```
sc = SparkContext(master="local[*]", appName="test")
spark = SparkSession(sc).builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark') \
    .option('hbase.table', 'h_table') \
    .option('hbase.columns.mapping',
            'life_id STRING :key, score STRING info:total_score') \
    .option('hbase.use.hbase.context', False) \
    .option('hbase.config.resources', 'file:///home/softs/hbase-2.0.5/conf/hbase-site.xml') \
    .option('hbase-push.down.column.filter', False) \
    .load()

df.show()
```

it shows: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`

I followed the [demo](https://diogoalexandrefranco.github.io/interacting-with-hbase-from-pyspark/)

Answer (score 1):

The dependency is not packaged with your JAR. Use the **—packages** flag of spark-submit to pas the uri of the connector you are using if you don’t wish to package the dependency in your project

add the following lines to your `spark-submit` command:

```
--packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/
```

and it should work.

Comment: @littlely could you share your pom.xml or build.sbt file you are using for the code

Comment: This is pyspark, I have no porm.xml.

Comment: @littlely try this link. The person has found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826218/what-is-the-best-possible-way-of-interacting-with-hbase-using-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment96435984_54826218) for PySpark