# Storing dataframe into HBase using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, connector

I am storing dataframe to hbase table from the pyspark dataframe in CDP7, following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826218/what-is-the-best-possible-way-of-interacting-with-hbase-using-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment96435984_54826218), the components that I use are:

- Spark version 3.1.1
- Scala version 2.12.10
- shc-core-1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11.jar

The command that i use:

```
spark3-submit  --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml test-hbase3.py
```

However, I got this error, it is quite long that I need to put it in hastebin.com as below:
[spark-log](https://hastebin.com/ulahesoliw.sql)

error snippet:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.6-1.cdh7.1.6.p0.10506313/test-hbase3.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.6-1.cdh7.1.6.p0.10506313/test-hbase3.py", line 24, in main
    writeDF.write.options(catalog=writeCatalog, newtable=5).format(dataSourceFormat).save()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253-1.p0.11638568/lib/spark3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1107, in save
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253-1.p0.11638568/lib/spark3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253-1.p0.11638568/lib/spark3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3-3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253-1.p0.11638568/lib/spark3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.<init>(HBaseRelation.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
```

What should I do to fix the error? I tried to find other connector. However, only found SHC connector. Im not using any Maven repo here. But, not sure if there is missing dependencies or other error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scala version conflict. Your shc_core.jar is compiled for scala 2.11 but you're using scala 2.12 which is not binary compatible with 2.11.

Easiest fix would be to recompile shc_core from source for scala 2.12 (although you may end up with compatibility issues since the project is
obviously not tested with scala 2.12)

Other ways you can explore to solve your issue:

- accessing HBase through a Hive table (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/hbase-data-access/content/hdag_hbase_hive_integration_example.html)
- using something like Phoenix connector (https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.8/phoenix-access-data/topics/phoenix-spark-connector-examples.html)
- rolling your own connector with HBase API for your data frame, it's fairly straightforward if you're not trying to implement a fully generic solution

Comment: for scala 2.12 issue, even so I've downgraded my terminal env to scala 2.11, i still having the same issue when using the sch_core.jar . any idea on this conflict?

Comment: Hmm... duplicated scala libraries of different minor versions in the spark application class path is the most likely cause